# serialization and utf-8 in PHP

Tags: php, serialization

Hi All
I'm trying to serialize array that contains some utf-8 code:

```
....["value"]=>  string(13) "مغادرة1"....
```

but after serializing the array,it look like this:

```
value";s:13:"??????
```

I think that the error that i get:

```
Message: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 685 of 701 bytes
```

is related to wrong serialization to utf-8 code
So How to serialize array that contains utf-8 code?
Thank You

Comment: Can you provide some short piece of code that clearly demonstrates this problem? Like: `$s = serialize(array('value' => 'مغادرة1')); unserialize($s);`.

Comment: Yes, please show more detail. What are you doing with the serialized data?

Answer (score 5):

Thank's for all replies
The problem was in storing the data in the database,and not in serialization,
the type of field that i stored the ser content was latin,i change it to utf-8 and everything works fine